# C programming HWND

Tags: c, winapi, hwnd

When I compile my code, a window should be opened but it does not. I have created a class, HWND, and application handlers; still nothing.

I am kinda new, sorry about the question.

The application runs fine without errors, but the window does not seem to appear.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>


LRESULT CALLBACK myCallBack(HWND regularWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam){
    switch(message){
    case 0x0201:
    printf("left Click");
    MessageBox(regularWnd, "Left Click", "event handler", MB_OK);
    break;
    case WM_CLOSE: 
    DestroyWindow(regularWnd);
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
    default:
    DefWindowProc(regularWnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE newHInstance, HINSTANCE prevHINSTANCE, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int cmdShow){

    WNDCLASSEX regularWndClass;

    regularWndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    regularWndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    regularWndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    regularWndClass.style = 0;
    regularWndClass.lpszClassName = "regularWindowClass";
    regularWndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    regularWndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+2);
    regularWndClass.lpfnWndProc = myCallBack;
    regularWndClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    regularWndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    regularWndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    regularWndClass.hInstance = newHInstance;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&regularWndClass) < 0){
        perror("Error Wnd class: ");
        exit(0);
    }

    HWND regularWnd;

    regularWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "regularWindowClass", "The title of my window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 300, 300, NULL, NULL, newHInstance, NULL);

    if(regularWnd < 0){
        perror("window error : ");
        exit(0);
    }

    ShowWindow(regularWnd, cmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(regularWnd);

    MSG message;
    while(GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0){
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
    return message.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `CreateWindowEx()` will set `errno`. Change this to use `GetLastError()` and `FormatMessage()` -- but that's just a hint ;)

Comment: I recommend you to carefully read the documentation of the `ShowWindow` function on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Don't use `perror`, because that checks `errno`, which isn't used by Win32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate error is in this line:

```
DefWindowProc(regularWnd, message, wparam, lparam);
```

A window procedure is supposed to return an `LRESULT` and `DefWindowProc` does this when necessary, but you don't pass it along. Change this to

```
return DefWindowProc(regularWnd, message, wparam, lparam);
```

and your window will appear as expected.

Apart from that, the [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi) doesn't use `errno`, so `perror()` will not work. You have to use `GetLastError()` and `FormatMessage()` for meaningful error messages, and with `WinMain()` (which strongly suggests subsystem `windows`), you won't have a console per default to display them ....

Finally, `UpdateWindow()` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: `WinMain` is just a user-provided entry point. It doesn't by itself control, which subsystem the program runs in. The [/SUBSYSTEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem) linker option does.

Comment: I didn't say anything about "controlling". But using `WinMain` clearly documents that this will be built as "windows subsystem".

Comment: *"`WinMain()` (which means subsystem `windows`)"* - This is wrong. `WinMain` is just a symbol. By **convention**, this is used for applications that run in the WINDOWS subsystem.

Comment: @IInspectable it's only "wrong" if you insist on understanding it wrong and it's not at all the point of the question *or* my hint: OP is writing a *windows* program, so `stdio` won't be usable without preparation.

Comment: This is an unconditional statement, and it is wrong. There is no interpretation required. And since it's part of your answer, I pointed it out, so that you can improve it. One way of putting it would be, that [WinMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559.aspx) *"is the conventional name [used for] the user-provided entry point for a graphical Windows-based application"*.

Comment: @IInspectable It's not the point and using `WinMain()` **means** `windows` subsystem. No clarification required **at all** about the details if the question isn't about this. It's not just *conventional*, Microsoft **intends** `WinMain()` to be used *for windows programs*.

Comment: Yes, precisely. *"Intends"*. Your statement would be correct if that read *"enforces"*. It doesn't, and the symbol is the **conventional** name of the user-provided entry point. Whatever, if you insist that you don't need to improve your answer, I'm not going to change that.

Comment: I just don't think it would be an improvement. "Means" doesn't have exact semantics, and although I'm all for exact answers, I personally don't think elaborating on an aspect not directly related is helpful. But I could change a single word to prevent misunderstandings...

Answer (score 1):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK myCallBack(HWND regularWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message) {
        case 0x0201:
            printf("left Click");
            MessageBox(regularWnd, "Left Click", "event handler", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(regularWnd);
            return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(regularWnd, message, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Change your window procedure to this

Also, use `GetLastError` and `FormatMessage` to print errors; not `perror`, that's or C standard library calls. Here's an example of how to use this function

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582(v=vs.85).aspx